# How to access a database file .MDF from R

Tags: sql-server, r, adventureworks

I am trying to connect to the AdventureWorks2012 database (MDF file) from R. The file is stored on my local computer. I have been able to setup SQl Server and the SQL Server Management Studio.

In Server Management Studio I have my PC name (2NDHANDBRUTUS) as the server and I can find AdventureWorks2012 :
[image: Server Management Studio]

However, I am not able to connect to it via R through the odbcConnect() statements. I have setup the following datasource:\

[image: Data source setup through ODBC Data Source Administrator]

I have tried the following R command:

```
CON <- odbcConnect('AdventureWorks2012', uid = 'Rob Oudehand', pwd = 'Hondenmand5')
```

And I receive this error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=AdventureWorks2012;UID=Rob Oudehand;PWD=Hondenmand5") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
2: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=AdventureWorks2012;UID=Rob Oudehand;PWD=Hondenmand5") :
  ODBC connection failed
```

Can someone assist me in how I should access such a MDF-file from R? Should it be done via SQl Server via ODBSConnect, or is there another way?

Comment: You have named the ODBC DSN "AdventureWorksDW" but referenced it as "AdventureWorks2012". Try changing that and see what you get.